# SendGrid issue "{"errors":[{"message":"Maximum credits exceeded","field":null,"help":null}]}"

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio, sendmail, sendgrid

I am getting error response "{"errors":[{"message":"Maximum credits exceeded","field":null,"help":null}]}" while using sendgrid service to send emails.

```
        SendGridClient client = new SendGridClient("SG.************************************************");

        var from = new EmailAddress("test@testdomain.com");
        var subject = "Testing SendGrid";
        var to = new EmailAddress("test@yopmail.com");
        var plainTextContent = "SendGrid is Working";
        var htmlContent = "<strong>SendGrid is Working</strong>";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        var responseBody = response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I believe you just left a [similar comment on a SendGrid library issue](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/1032#issuecomment-925564268). The answer you need for now is in the comment above though. SendGrid Support has the tools to help debug these kinds of issues. Please [open a new support ticket](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us) to get help with this error.

Comment: Yes! but the issue is it works after 09:00 AM (UTC Time), which is very weird!

Comment: Definitely sounds like an issue for the support team!

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/60603 . Also can you please tell which subscription you are using and also how many email you are sending. SendGrid may have  throttling mechanism and also your subscription has certain limit.

Comment: @dotnetstep yes you are right! But why the service gets working after 09:00 AM (UTC Time).

Answer (score 1):

As there were some misunderstandings and some random emails by our team, were sent in the beginning of the day, that caused the credits of sendgrid service to finish. So I had to exceed the credits.